# How to understand variable-length argument in python function?

Tags: python

I want to write my own sum function to get the sum of a  variable-length argument.

```
def myadd(*tuple):
    sum=0
    for element in tuple:
        sum=sum+element
    return(sum)
```

call method 1:

```
myadd(*(1,2,3,4))
```

It is the most formal way to call the function.no problem here.

call method 2:

```
myadd(1,2,3,4)
```

It also can get the result,why?

call method 3:

```
myadd((1,2,3,4))
```

error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'.

In my point of view,call 2 and call 3 can not be accepted by python,there are no * operator in the position of arguments?can you tell me the pricinple of the operation on python function ?

Comment: What do you expect `0 + (1, 2，3)` to be?

Comment: The obvious question is: What is wrong with the built-in sum function?

Comment: As a side note, you really shouldn't call your parameter `tuple`, as that hides the name of the `tuple` type/constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing up variable-argument parameters and argument unpacking. This is a common mistake for beginners, because they both use the same `*` for syntax, and they're not completely unrelated… but they're not nearly as closely related as you think.

---

These two calls do the exact same thing:

```
myadd(*(1,2,3,4))
myadd(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

What the `*` means here is "take the following iterable, and unpack it into a bunch of separate arguments.

It doesn't matter whether the function you're calling was defined as `f(*args)`, `f(a, b, c, d)`, or `f(a, b, *args)`, you're passing it 4 arguments.

This means method 1 is not "the most formal way to call the function"; in fact, it's just an obfuscated version of method 2.

---

This, on the other hand, does not do the same thing:

```
myadd((1, 2, 3, 4))
```

That passes a single argument, which happens to be a tuple.

---

So, your function is defined like this:

```
def myadd(*tuple):
```

This means whatever it arguments it's passed, no matter how they're passed (except for keyword arguments, but let's ignore that for the moment), they're going to be tossed into a list named `tuple`. So, let's look at your three cases.

In the first case, you're passing 4 arguments, all of which are integers. So, `tuple` gets a list of 4 integers. When you iterate over that list, each member is an integer, so you can add them up with no problem.

In the second case—which, again, is exactly the same—you're passing 4 integers, so `tuple` gets a list of 4 integers.

In the third case, you're passing 1 argument, which is a tuple, so `tuple` gets a list of 1 tuple. When you iterate over that list, each member is a tuple, and you can't add that to a number.

---

For more details, see [Arguments and parameters](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/arguments-and-parameters.html), which has links to all the useful places to look in the docs, and hopefully a readable overview.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the whole tuple as one argument, and tuples cannot be added to numbers. If you want to pass all the tuple elements as individual arguments, use the `*` operator:

```
myadd(*x)
```

Comment: i almost get it ,the function is right,the call method is wrong.myadd(*(1,2,3)) is ok.

Comment: i know myadd(*(1,2,3,4)) can get result,why myadd(1,2,3,4) can get result also?it is not the form of *tuple ?there is no * operator here,can you talk more about the principle of function in python?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature What about reading a tutorial and/or the manual? This is really basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
def myadd(x):                                
    sum=0                                    
    for element in x:                        
        sum=sum+element                      
    return(sum)                              

x=(1,2,3)                                    
print myadd(x)
```

**output**

```
6
```